# shutdown command loops batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7-x64, shutdown

I found very strange problem with `.bat` file in Windows 7.

**Code:**

```
@echo off
"C:\program files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS3\Photoshop.exe"
shutdown /s
```

After closing Photoshop, PC doesn't shut down. It starts Photoshop again and again. If i remove `shutdown` it works correctly. What is wrong with shutting down?

Comment: Is your batch file named `shutdown`? If it is, it is calling itself.